# How to write in letters numbers that have symbols in between?

Tags: orthography, numbers

I am translating a document that has the identification numbers 2017-976 written in letters this way: two thousand seventeen-nine hundred seventy-six. I was doubting about placing the dash like that between seventeen and nine. Should I write "dash" instead? What would be a proper way of writing said numbers with the dash in between? And how to write them with other symbols (+, x, @, etc)?

It is a legal document and the document identification number is, say, FRG-2017-976, but in the original document they both write it like this in parenthesis and spelled out in letters.

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? What type of document is the original text (e.g. instruction manual, nonfiction book, fiction), and is there some reason for preferring to spell out the numbers rather than writing them exactly as "2017-976"?

Comment: Where you suspect that the formatting carries some meaning, you should err on the side of clarity and say "dash" (or "space" or whatever).

Comment: This gets very messy; I believe the hyphen is often read as 'dash' in this context. // I'd copy and paste if I couldn't find an authority or recommended style guide to endorse one format. But this is outside the scope of normal everyday English and would almost certainly be better asked on a dedicated website.

Comment: @sumelic It is a legal document and the document identification number is, say, FRG-2017-976, but in the original document they both write it like this in parenthesis and spelled out in letters.

Comment: How numbers are spelled out differs from person to person and place to place. A Yank might pronounce a phone extension of 5336 as *fifty-three thirty-six* but a Brit would probably not, and might say something like *five double-three six* which would sound utterly bizarre to the American. What locale are you interested in?

Comment: @choster Im interested in cases when there is a symbol, specially a hyphen or dash, in between two numbers. American locale.